# If statement in vcl_fetch not working

Tags: c, boolean, varnish, varnish-vcl

Trying to remove a cookie only if the url is not like "demo/secured"

In the default.vcl I have:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
#    error 200 req.url ~ ".*/demo/secured/.*";
    if (req.url ~ ".*/demo/secured/.*") {
      set beresp.http.x-whaaat = "this is demo securd";
    }else {
      unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
      set beresp.http.x-whaaat = "not demo secured";
    }
}
```

Both url's with or without /demo/secured result in a x-whaaat response header of "not demo secured". But uncommenting the error 200 line gives error 200 true for url's with demo/secured and error 200 false for url's without demo/secured.

I tried a gazillion and one variations of that if statement but can't get it to return anything other than false.

The following is true:

```
if ( "/app_dev.php/demo/secured/login" ~ ".*/demo/secured/.*" )
```

Even though I copied and pasted "/app_dev.php/demo/secured/login" from the page output of `error 200 req.url` the following isn't true:

```
#    error 200 req.url;
    if ( req.url ~ ".*/demo/secured/.*" ) {
      set beresp.http.x-whaaat = "this is demo securd";
    }else {
      unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
      set beresp.http.x-whaaat = "not demo secured";
    }
```

gives me a "x-whaat not demo secured" header on `http://site/app_dev.php/demo/secured/login` not sure how this is possible because the same url gives me "/app_dev.php/demo/secured/login" when uncommenting the error 200 line.

```
varnishd -V
```

gives me:

```
varnishd (varnish-3.0.5 revision 1a89b1f)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Varnish Software AS
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong request in firebug/chrome dev tool. The request I was inspecting was a xhr request made to mysite.com/app_dev.php/_wdt/60c03d and that doesn't have /demo/secured so sure enough it has the right headers.

Time to walk away from the computer for a while now, continue tomorrow.